# How to list all delegates from a .NET assembly

Tags: .net, delegates, .net-assembly

To get a list off classes defined in a particular .NET assembly and a given namespace I would do something like:

```
foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Namespace == @namespace))
{
    //process type
}
```

This returns classes and delegates, so if there is a delegate declaration like

```
public delegate void MyDelegate()
```

`MyDelegate` also is processed by the above loop.

I would like to loop only through delegate types.
I would expect Type class have something like `IsDelegate` property but there is none.

I see that the types representing delegates have base type `System.MulticastDelegate` - is it the correct filter or am I missing something?

Comment: Check if the type is assignable to `Delegate` (or `MulticastDelegate`, no difference in real world)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Namespace == @namespace && t.IsDelegate()))
{                
    //process delegate type
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static bool IsDelegate(this Type type)
    {
        return type.BaseType == typeof(MulticastDelegate);
    }
}
```